# get className of a reusable component from html

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, components

I'm doing a web scraping project an ineeded to scrape this site for test : https://quotes.toscrape.com/js/

###### The HTML:

```
<div class="quote" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
    <span class="text" itemprop="text">“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”</span>
    <span>by <small class="author" itemprop="author">Albert Einstein</small>
    <a href="/author/Albert-Einstein">(about)</a>
    </span>
    <div class="tags">
        Tags:
        <meta class="keywords" itemprop="keywords" content="change,deep-thoughts,thinking,world" /    > 
        
        <a class="tag" href="/tag/change/page/1/">change</a>
        
        <a class="tag" href="/tag/deep-thoughts/page/1/">deep-thoughts</a>
        
        <a class="tag" href="/tag/thinking/page/1/">thinking</a>
        
        <a class="tag" href="/tag/world/page/1/">world</a>
        
    </div>
</div>

<div class="quote" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
    <span class="text" itemprop="text">“It is our choices, Harry, that show what we truly are, far more than our abilities.”</span>
    <span>by <small class="author" itemprop="author">J.K. Rowling</small>
    <a href="/author/J-K-Rowling">(about)</a>
    </span>
    <div class="tags">
        Tags:
        <meta class="keywords" itemprop="keywords" content="abilities,choices" /    > 
        
        <a class="tag" href="/tag/abilities/page/1/">abilities</a>
        
        <a class="tag" href="/tag/choices/page/1/">choices</a>
        
    </div>
</div>.....
```

So, there is this reusable component with className quote.
My question is, how to auto detected and get the className with js ?

Comment: unclear how you expect JavaScript to determine a random classname. Maybe I am not sure what exactly you are asking.

Comment: that exacty my question, idk maybe by detecting a pattern

Comment: Then you are going to be coding some crazy logic to determine that. There is nothing that will figure that out for you. Why can you not use `quote`?

Comment: it's for an app and i dont whant user to inspect the html and find the class name by him self, cz im expecting a non technical users to use my app

Comment: Well good luck trying to figure that out since that is a lot harder problem than you may think it is.

Answer (score 0):

I have not clearly understand but read about querySelector

in your case:

```
const element = document.querySelectorAll(".quote")
```

Comment: i need same thing that can detect this class name without giving it any input. thank you any way